# What is the scope of a public Angular2+ class property?

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular2+ application, if I declare a public property in a component e.g. 'foo':

```
@Component({
     selector: 'my-component',
     templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
}) 

export class MyComponent {

     foo: string; 

}
```

If I were to create another component MyComponent2 that has the same property name 'foo', will these still be independant properties only associated with the relevant class i.e. myComponent.foo is different to myComponent2.foo?

Comment: yes, they are..

Comment: Yes, they will be independent. I don't know any language where they will be the same. In fact, when TS is compiled into JS there's no visibility restriction so everything is public.

Comment: Yes I had a assumed that - how difficult would it be if they were not! The doubt I had was about the fact that everything is public in JS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..

"yes, they are" – *Gourishankar*

"Yes, they will be independent. I don't know any language where they will be the same. In fact, when TS is compiled into JS there's no visibility restriction so everything is public." – *Maximus*